# Ajax is not posting datas to php file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send the datas by using ajax to php file and check them in php file. But ajax is not posting datas. Ajax code below

```
$('button#submit').click(function () {

    $.post($('#login-form').attr('action'),
        $('#login-form :input').serializeArray(),
        function(data){
        if(data == "Ok")
        {
            window.location.href = data;
        }
        else
        {alert(data.d);}

        });

    $('#login-form').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
```

});

Form part

```
<form action="giriskontrol.php" method="post" id="login-form">
<div id="rgesc-admin-container">
<input type="text" class="rgesc-kadi" name="admin-kadi" id="kadi"/>
<input type="password" class="rgesc-pass" name="admin-pass" id="kpass"/>
<button id="submit" class="rgesc-login"> </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Php part

```
<?php
include ("../config.php");

$kadi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["admin-kadi"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["admin-pass"]);
$cryptedPass= sha1($pass);

if(empty($kadi) || empty($pass)){
echo "Boş Alan Bırakmayın!"; }
else{
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE username='$kadi' AND password='$cryptedPass'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if($row[0] > 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$kadi' AND password='$cryptedPass'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $get = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $get['username'];
    $_SESSION['adminid'] = $get['id'];
    echo "url";
}
else
{
    echo "Böyle bir kayıt bulunmamaktadır!.";
}
```

}
?>

Included `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>` between head tags. When I input ajax part by usinf firebug console, it works. But not working as included between head tags.

Comment: Try adding document ready around it?

Comment: yes I tried to add document ready.

Comment: Well.. otherwise, your never send `Ok` back, so you never get in your `if` statement.

Comment: Normally, ajax part is working when I input it from FireBug Console, but not working when I refresh the page, it is redirecting me to giriskontrol.php page